# xElement.Descendants returns combined values "falsefalse"

Tags: c#, arrays, xml

I am using the following XML document to control the visibility of controls using bools.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Testy>
  <Buttons>
    <boolean>false</boolean> <!-- button1 -->
    <boolean>false</boolean> <!-- button2 -->
  </Buttons>
</Testy>
```

I am attempting to make a bool array based on the boolean values seen in the XML. Here is the following code I am using.

```
private void testy()
{
    XElement xElement = XElement.Load("Testy.xml");
    Buttons = xElement.Descendants("Buttons").Select(b =>XmlConvert.ToBoolean(b.Value)).ToArray();
}
```

The only issue, is that it is unable to convert to bool as the string seems to be combining. The specific error is "System.FormatException: 'The string 'falsefalse' is not a valid Boolean value.'"

How do I get these to separate and convert to bool individually and add to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently finding all descendants called `Buttons` - you have *one* element called `Buttons`, which has two child elements. The `Value` property of `XElement` will return all the descendant text node values, concatenated - which is why you're getting "falsefalse" as the value.

Instead, I believe you want to select the `boolean` children of the `Buttons` element. I'd do that like this:

```
Buttons = xElement
    .Element("Buttons")
    .Elements("boolean")
    .Select(b => (bool) b)
    .ToArray();
```

Note that this is using the explicit [`XElement` to `bool` conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.op_explicit?view=netframework-4.8#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_op_Explicit_System_Xml_Linq_XElement__System_Boolean) rather than calling `XmlConvert.ToBoolean` - it's just a bit simpler.

I've assumed that:

- There's a single `Buttons` element
- It's an immediate child of the root element
- The elements you want are always immediate children of `Buttons`
- The elements you want are always called `boolean`